# Cell State and Openers in 11.1 documentation

Tags: front-end, dynamic, cells, documentation

So I've been playing with the new 11.1 documentation style and I noticed that there's something seemingly odd with the openers.

If we open any doc page:

`` Documentation`HelpLookup@"TaggingRules" ``

And look at any of the section openers we see they're something custom:

[image: opener]

But they work totally normally. And looking at how they're implemented we see a general pattern like:

```
Dynamic@
 CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
  {TaggingRules, "Openers", style},
  Closed]
```

(where `style` is sometimes more deeply nested, like `"ExamplesSection", "0"`).

And interestingly we can open and close the groups via:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
  {TaggingRules, "Openers", style}] = Open | Closed
```

And this gets updated when the cell group is opened and closed by hand, too.

If we copy and paste one of these cells the behavior is preserved, but if we take the cell expression and reprint it using `NotebookWrite` it no longer works. The cell group will open and close because it has `WholeCellGroupOpener->True` but the opener won't toggle states and we can't close it via `CurrentValue`.

If I look at the `Cell` expressions there's no difference, so what causes this?

#### Update for clarity:

I expected to see grouping from the automatic grouping that Mathematica applies. I figured the grouping behavior would be handled somehow in the `Cell` expression because copying one of the `CellObjects` yielded the opening behavior I originally saw. It turns out the `CellObject` simply remembered the grouping spec.

Answer (score 7):

If we look at the `CellGroup` expressions we find our answer.

When we copy the `Cell` expression, we find the grouping acts in the standard way with `Open` and `Closed` being assigned to the state.

However if we look at the grouping for the originals or the copies we get:

```
Dynamic[
 CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
  {TaggingRules,"Openers",___},
  Closed
 ]
```

It's this that updates when the `CellGroup` is opened or closed and it is this that drives the behavior we observe.

Moreover, we can make a new group thing with this behavior:

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[
  CellGroupData[{
    Cell["Try Me", "Section",
     WholeCellGroupOpener -> True,
     Background ->
      Dynamic[
       If[
        MatchQ[
         CurrentValue[
          EvaluationNotebook[],
          {TaggingRules, "TryMeState"},
          Closed], True | Open
         ],
        None,
        Gray
        ]
       ]
     ],
    Cell["Now I see", "Text"]
    },
   Dynamic[
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
     {TaggingRules, "TryMeState"}, Closed]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

And if we copy that header cell to a new notebook we see it preserves its `CellGroup` state.

It would be nice if there were a way to know when a `CellObject` has this kind of hidden state--and if there were a way to specify it in the `Cell` expression--but I have yet to find a way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56904/discussion-between-mb1965-and-kuba).