# Cell @ CellGroupData[... in Cells family

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, cells, documentation

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

---

#### Background

*This question originates from two already posted questions updated with further doubts I've faced. I deleted one and merged content here.*

*Those issues are closely related, hard to separate and probably could be caused by the same internal features so I decided to make one question*

---

#### CellGroupData assumptions

First of all, according to [tutorial/TheStructureOfCells](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfCells.html) a cell of the form `Cell[CellGroupData[...],...]` is a valid `Cell` so in my opinion we should expect consistent behavior.

`CellGroupData` second argument allows to specify which cells are visible. It could be `Open`, `Closed`, `{cells indices}`, or even `{}` to show no cell.

That is not the case in general:

#### Issues

1. Inner `CellGroupData` expression are transparent to parent's visibility spec:

   ```
   CellGroupData[
      { Cell[...] 
      , Cell @ CellGroupData[...]
      , Cell[...] 
      }
    , {2}
   ]
   ```

   I'd expect the structure above to show only and exactly what `Cell @ CellGroupData[...]` contains.

   It is not the case, the outer `CellGroupData` can't handle nested structure this way and just goes into deeper `CellGroups` which is unintuitive and contradicts `CellGroupData` documentation.

   Try yourself

   ```
   Notebook[
       { Cell @ CellGroupData[
             { Cell["1", "Text"] 
             , Cell @ CellGroupData[
                  {Cell["2-1", "Text"], Cell["2-2", "Text"]}]
             , Cell["3", "Text"]        
             }
           , {3}
         ]   
       }
     , CellGrouping -> Manual
     , ShowGroupOpener -> False
   ] // NotebookPut
   ```

---

2. Visibility spec problem for single cell `CellGroupData`

   But if the group contains only one cell the `{}` visibility spec does not work:

   ```
   Notebook[{
      Cell @ CellGroupData[{ Cell["Group 1", "Chapter"] }, Open],
      Cell @ CellGroupData[{Cell["Group 2", "Chapter"]}, {}]
      },
     CellGrouping -> Manual
   ] // NotebookPut
   ```

   Add a second cell to the second group and it will disappear!

---

3. `Cell @ CellGroupData` as a first cell in `Cell @ CellGroupData`

   When the first cell in a group contains another `CellGroupData` then the parent `CellGroupData` is confused.

   Not only `{}` will still show whole group but even giving specific `{1}` cell position fails.

   ```
   Notebook[{
      Cell @ CellGroupData[{ Cell["Group 1", "Chapter"] }, Open],
      Cell @ CellGroupData[
          { (*Cell["","Text"],*) (*uncomment this cell and everything is ok*)
            Cell @ CellGroupData[{
                Cell["Group 2", "Chapter"], Cell["Group 2", "Text"]
            }]
          , Cell["text", "Text"]
          }
        , {2}
      ]}
    , CellGrouping -> Manual
   ] // NotebookPut
   ```

   [image]

---

4. Deletion of `CellGroups` in `Editable -> False` notebook

   You can delete each cell one by one, even those from the cell group. But if you try to delete after selecting group bracket you will get a *beep* and won't be able to delete it.

   ```
   CreateDocument[
    { Cell @ CellGroupData[{
         Cell["1", "Text"]
       , Cell["2", "Text"]
      }]
    , Cell["2", "Text"]
    }
    , CellGrouping -> Manual
    , Editable -> False
   ]
   ```

   Whatever editable means, this is at least inconsistent.

---

#### Further reading

related to cell structure

- [Any manual on cell grouping management?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118649/5478)
- [Cells[] ignoring multiple style cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148509/5478)
- [NotebookImport ignoring multiple style cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133891/5478)

#### Questions

How to understand cell groups behavior? Seems detached from 'cells framework' for me. Not to mention a minimal documentation.

Classification of faced 'issues' will be appreciated.

Comment: some of those issues are already reported, will format an update about that soon.

Comment: One thing I find worth mentioning that's caused me a major amount of confusion once is that if you copy and paste a `CellObject` that heads a cell group, that `CellObject` remembers its `CellGroupData` visibility spec. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143306/cell-state-and-openers-in-11-1-documentation) for what caused me such confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] Thank you for consolidating all of the issues to a single StackExchange article. I have confirmed the behavior you are reporting in each of the four issues. I will add a link to this StackExchange article in the developers report I originally filed. [...]
>
> [CASE:3918002]