# CellGroup[] in current Notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells

I have used the Option Inspector to set `CellGrouping` to `Manual` for the current, selected Notebook.  Nonetheless, the following does *not* group these two cells together:

```
CellPrint[CellGroup[{TextCell["hello"], TextCell["goodbye"]}]]
```

Also, adding the second argument to `CellGroup[]` to specify which cell should be open, does not work.

Please note that both of these work if I create the cells in a new Notebook, created with `CellGrouping -> Manual`.

I saw the same behavior with `Cell[CellGroupData[...]]`.

What am I missing?

Comment: [cross posted in community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1302643)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are many issues related to cell groups structure: [SE / Cell @ CellGroupData in Cells family](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151337/5478)

And my rules of thumb, unfortunately, are:

- only use `CellGroup+TextCell+ExpressionCell` and friends, which are a higher level equivalents of `CellGroupData` and `Cell`, for small snippets rather than serious work. Why? I don't know, maybe I just can't handle them but writing your code in a low level form works:

  ```
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],  
    Cell@CellGroupData[{Cell["hello"], Cell["goodbye"]}]
  ]
  ```
- don't expect much from `Manual CellGrouping` with respect to other related options. Same reason.

You want more details? You can as WRI Support.

Comment: Kuba, thank you. [Here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1302962) is the parallel question at Wolfram.